# How to fix TypeError('Object of type ExternalUnifiedEvent is not JSON serializable)?

Tags: python, json, django, api, post

I am retrieving a list of objects from an external API that I need to send as the payload to a webhook using post request in python.

The structure of the data returned from `get_data()` looks like this

```
[{"eventId": 1,
"eventType": "test",
"properties": {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2",
    "property3": "value3",
}},
{"eventId": 2,
"eventType": "test",
"properties": {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2",
    "property3": "value3",
}},
{"eventId": 3,
"eventType": "test",
"properties": {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2",
    "property3": "value3",
}}]
```

```
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",}

payload = get_data()

response = requests.post(webhook_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

it raises a `TypeError('Object of type ExternalUnifiedEvent is not JSON serializable)`; if i remove the `json.dumps()` and just pass in the payload as the data, I'm getting `TypeError('cannot unpack non-iterable ExternalUnifiedEvent object')`

```
def get_data():

   try:
       api_response = client_api.get()
       data = []
       for i in api_reponse:
           e = {
               "event_id": i.event_id
               "event_type": i.event_type
               "properties": i.properties
            }
           data.append(e)
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: json only knows about standard data types -- strings, numbers, lists, etc.  If you want to dump a custom class object as json, you have to tell json how to do that.

Comment: So in the `get_data()` after I convert the data to string `str(response.results).replace("\'", "\"")` and then I also update the post request to be `response = requests.post(webhook_url, headers=headers, data=payload.encode('utf-8'))`. the request is returning 200 but data format still seem to be off even though it looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_data` function is returning an `ExternalUnifiedEvent` object instead of a list or another [JSON serializable object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table).
You should fix your `get_data` function or provide a custom `JSONDecoder` to the `dumps` method as a `cls` paramater:

```
json.dumps(payload, cls=YourCustomJSONEncoder)
```

You can see how to make your custom JSON encoder class in the [json python lib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Does that mean a dataclass is needed in this case since this is an external API response object?

Comment: You probably just need to access the data from the object before returning it from the `get_data` function; something like `return api_response.content` or `return api_response.to_s()`. Feel free to provide the `get_data` content so I can better help.
And don't forget to set the answer as correct if it answer the question, thank you!

Comment: I added the `get_data()` function and accessing the data and saving it to a list makes it work. I didn't have to create a custom Decoder because it is a python list and I can use `json.dumps` to pass it to a post request. Do you think this is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can improve a little using python list comprehension to build the data list. It's more pythonic and performant:
```data = [ { "event_id": event.event_id, "event_type": event.event_type, "properties": event.properties, } for event in api_response ]```